# spoeding up a "distinct" select with LIMIT x in postgres

Tags: performance, postgresql, database-optimization

The following query is very slow :

```
select distinct gene_symbol from my_table where gene_symbol like 'ED%' limit 15
```

which is not surprising, since the distinct causes it to do a hash aggregate.

This version runs a lot faster :

```
      with q0 as (
        SELECT gene_symbol from my_table WHERE gene_symbol like 'ED%' limit 200
      )
      select distinct gene_symbol from q0 limit 15
```

but the inconvenient is that I need to tweak the LIMIT of the inner query,
If I set it too high, it becomes slow, if I set it too low, I might get less than 15 rows.

Is there a better way ?

Comment: Unless you post your table structure including indexes and the output of explain analyse, it's a case of blind leading the blind

Answer (score 0):

the query seems simple, but I let some alternatives

```
SELECT gene_symbol FROM my_table GROUP 1 LIMIT 15;

SELECT p.gene_symbol
FROM
(SELECT
gene_symbol
FROM my_table GROUP 1) AS p
ORDER BY 1 DESC|ASC
LIMIT 15;
```

Comment: I have mistakenly left out the where like filter in the post, the question is not corrected. you second solution is as slow as the select distinct gene_symbol from my_table where gene_symbol like 'ED%' limit 15;

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct gene_symbol 
from my_table 
where gene_symbol like 'ED%' 
limit 15
```

Comment: appologies, that is actually the slow query, I have mistakenly left out the where like filter in the post...

Comment: @MaxL. If that is the case your _faster_ query makes no difference. Post `explain analyse` for both.